# Unable to get MicronautTest to work with a POST against the HttpClient

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-rest

I'm implementing a web API as a micronaut service. I have tests against the GET endpoints working, but cannot get the POST endpoints working correctly. I receive an error response 'BAD REQUEST'. The endpoint works correctly from command line `curl` or `http`(ie) POST requests.

The controller:

```java
@Controller("/people")
@ExecuteOn(TaskExecutors.IO)  //Make sure the controller is executed on a non-main thread pool so it does not block
public class PersonController {
   private final DataService dataSvc;

   public PersonController(final DataService dataSvc) {
    this.dataSvc = dataSvc;
  }

  //Various GET endpoints

  @Post   //I also tried adding '(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)'. This had no effect
  @Status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  public Person addPerson(@Valid @NotNull final Person person) {
    final Person p = dataSvc.save(person);
    //log it!
    return p;
  }
}
```

*I have an exception handler handling `Throwable` and returning 500 (INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR).*

*I also have a handler for `ConstraintViolationException`s, which returns a 412 (PRECONDITION_FAILED) response.*

Test that's failing is:

```java
@MicronautTest
public class PersonControllerClient {
  @Inject @Client("/people")
  HttpClient client;

  @Inject DataService dataSvc;
  final DataService mock = mock(DataService.class);

  //Various tests of the GET endpoints

  @Test
  @DisplayName("Add a person successfully")
  public void testAddPersonHappypath() {
    final Person.PersonBuilder pb = Person.builder().firstName("John").lastName("Doe");
    final Person in = pb.build();
    final Person expected = pb.id("1234").build();

    try {
      final HttpRequest<Person> request = HttpRequest.POST("/", in).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
      //Note - I also tried having the client '/', and the request endpoint '/people', which failed in the same manner
      //I also tried `HttpRequest.create(HttpMethod.POST, "/people").body(in)` with same result. 

      when(mock.save(in)).thenReturn(expected);

      final HttpResponse<Person> response = client.toBlocking().exchange(request, Person.class);
      assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED, response.getStatus());

      final Person body = response.body();
      assertNotNull(body);
      assertEquals(expected, body);
    } catch (HttpClientResponseException ex) {
      fail(String.format("Received exception (%s) - Status %d", ex.getMessage(), ex.getStatus().getCode()));
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I can see, this *should* succeed, but it is going to the `fail` (catch block).

I've tried stepping through the test and it doesn't seem to be making it into the `PersonController` code at all, so it's something with how the POST query is being constructed.

I'm assuming I'm creating the client incorrectly, but cannot see where. Any help would be appreciated.

> **Note** - I'm moving from SpringBoot to Micronaut. Not sure if I'm trying to apply Spring concepts where they shouldn't be!

#### More info

I have added tests for the DELETE method, which succeed (both happy and unhappy paths). It's ONLY the POST requests that fail, with BAD REQUEST

Also, probably useful to have the `Person` data object

```java
@MappedEntity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  String id;

  @NotEmpty(message="First name cannot be empty")
  String firstName;

  @NotEmpty(message="Last name cannot be empty")
  String lastName;

  int age;
}
```

*Lombok annotations to make this 'record'ish. Not actually using `Record` as the validation annotations can't be applied to fields of a record (`target` for `NotEmpty` and `Id` annotations does not include `RECORD_COMPONENT`)*

Comment: I suspect you miss the `@Body` annotation in the `addPerson` method argument - `@Valid @NotNull @Body final Person person`. Also, your test does not mock the `DataService` - if you want to mock it, you should use the `@MockBean` annotation to do so.

Comment: Thanks @Szymon . The DataService is mocked, or at least the mock as coded above works for all of the GET tests (and the DELETE test). WRT the `@body'`- I'll give that a go, but if that works I'll be more confused again. The endpoint as coded in the question works for manual tests (calls through postman, curl and httpie)

Comment: It worked! Thanks. @Szymon, can you post your comment as an answer and I'll accept? I could do it myself, but you don't get credit then! If you (know and) could address why it works from command line but not from the tests, that would be awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answer from comment from @szymon-stepniak*

Within the post method declaration, make sure there is a `@Body` annotation on the incoming data packet

```java
@Controller("/people")
// ...
public class PersonController {
   // ...

  @Post
  @Status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  public Person addPerson(@Valid @NotNull @Body final Person person) {
    //Note the `@Body` in the method definition

    final Person p = dataSvc.save(person);
    //log it!
    return p;
  }
}
```

Unsure why the endpoint would work but the test client fails without the annotation, but BOTH work if the annotation is added.

Comment: @szymon-stepniak, deserves credit for this, based on his comment. If you post an answer, I'll remove this and accept yours to give credit